# Colon or comma in this sentence

Tags: punctuation

> 1. This is a frozen pack. To cook, bake for 20 minutes at 200 degrees celsius.
> 2. This is a frozen pack. To cook: bake for 20 minutes at 200 degrees celsius.

Is colon correctly used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing ordinary sentences, the colon is incorrect. The rules require the text to the left of the colon to be able to stand on its own as a grammatically complete sentence. #1 is the correct sentence.

However, if you are writing instructions (something you might find on a package, for instance) then you may adapt the rules to suit your needs. It is quite common for instructions to use sentences like #2. The correctness would be determined by the manufacturer, perhaps with reference to an in-house style manual.